# SQL find record that matches in any of three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I have the following schema:

```
user -- user_id | first_name
full_time_job -- ft_job_id | user_id
part_time_job -- pt_job_id | user_id
internship -- internship_id | user_id
```

I'd like to write a query that returns all users that exist in any of the three job tables.  What's the best way to do this? I'd prefer to use LEFT JOINS over WHERE EXISTS if possible, but will be happy with the best working solution.

I do NOT want to return any users that exist in NONE of the three job tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LEFT JOIN`s, you merely need to verify that `user_id` is `NOT NULL` in at least one of the tables:

```
SELECT
  [user].user_id
FROM
  [user]
  /* LEFT JOIN against each of the 3 tables */
  LEFT JOIN full_time_job ft ON [user].user_id = ft.user_id
  LEFT JOIN part_time_job pt ON [user].user_id = pt.user_id
  LEFT JOIN internship intern ON [user].user_id = intern.user_id
WHERE
  /* And check that *any* of them has a non-null user_id */
  ft.user_id IS NOT NULL
  OR pt.user_id IS NOT NULL
  OR intern.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

#### Best to fix the schema if possible...

In the long run though, if possible these should all probably be combined into a *single* table that has a column indicating the job type, rather than 3 similar tables.

**Sample:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cd2c/1

In the above example, users `5,6` don't exist in any of the 3 tables.

Comment: I do like this answer, except it's coming back with WAY too many results.  Some users may have matches in one or more of the job tables.  But in any case, this is running slow and returning over a million results. It should be closer to 750.  I did add distinct, which brought the number down to about 4000.

Comment: @AdamLevitt What is your implementation? If the join `ON` conditions are correct, you should _not_ be getting any more rows than expected.  If you are missing any of the `ON` clauses, you'll get the cartesian product which causes you to need the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I cut and pasted your exact code actually, I just swapped out the table names with the ones in my actual schema.

Comment: @AdamLevitt `user.user_id` is unique/PK?  Check carefully over the table names, especially in the `ON` clauses because there's no way this can return more or duplicate users if they're unique.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the unique PK for the user table.  Strange, I know... but definitely unique. Also for completeness, perhaps you should put [user] as the user table just to avoid any downvotes from people.  I've seen it happen.

Comment: Yep, and I appreciate your excellent answer along with the fiddle.  One thing that may be causing the duplicates is that a user can have more than one record in any job table.  Perhaps that's why I need distinct?

Comment: @AdamLevitt Yes, that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_id
IN
(
    SELECT user_id
    FROM
    (
       SELECT user_id FROM full_time_job
       UNION ALL
       SELECT user_id FROM part_time_job
       UNION ALL
       SELECT user_id FROM internship 
   ) t 
   WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
)
```

**Or:** Using a CTE, you can write it this way:

```
;WITH AllUsers
AS
(
    SELECT user_id FROM full_time_job
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id FROM part_time_job
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id FROM internship 
)
SELECT *
FROM "user"
WHERE user_id IN ( SELECT user_id 
                   FROM AllUsers 
                   WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05656/1)